# SQL Server 2005: How Secure is SQL Server Authentication?

Tags: sql-server, security, authentication

If you use SQL Server Authentication (2005), are the login details sent in clear text over the wire?

Comment: Thanks all, I am now pretty sure that the login credentials are passed as a hash, over SSL.  However, there is a degree of ambiguity and even contradiction in the MS documentation that you have uncovered.  I have commented on this on your answers and up-voted where applicable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As secure as you want to make it...

you can configure SSL fairly easily, and if you don't have a trusted cert, if you force encryption, SQL Server can create/issue it's own self signed cert for your use...[from this write-up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx)

> Credentials (in the login packet) that
>   are transmitted when a client
>   application connects to SQL Server are
>   always encrypted. SQL Server will use
>   a certificate from a trusted
>   certification authority if available.
>   If a trusted certificate is not
>   installed, SQL Server will generate a
>   self-signed certificate when the
>   instance is started, and use the
>   self-signed certificate to encrypt the
>   credentials. This self-signed
>   certificate helps increase security
>   but it does not provide protection
>   against identity spoofing by the
>   server. If the self-signed certificate
>   is used, and the value of the
>   ForceEncryption option is set to Yes,
>   all data transmitted across a network
>   between SQL Server and the client
>   application will be encrypted using
>   the self-signed certificate

Comment: Agreed, but all of this encryption effort eliminates the performance advantage of using SQL authentication. But then, not everyone has a choice of using Windows authentication.

Comment: that's the classic trade-off, ain't it, performance versus security?

Comment: Still not 100% sure that SQL credentials are always sent securely, but I think your link is about as clear as MS have made it.  'Credentials (in the login packet) that are transmitted when a client application connects to SQL Server are always encrypted', but given this phrase comes halfway through a a section for how to setup SQL to use SSL it's still slightly ambiguous (or maybe I am being too cautious!)

Comment: @NoelKennedy, you are right to be cautious! TDS (the protocol used between client and SQL Server) does support completely unencrypted logins--see heading *Encryption* on [MS-TDS 2.2.6.5 PRELOGIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd357559.aspx). My guess is that unencrypted logins are rare. However, they are possible. I've successfully used them in a test environment when testing driver-level code against SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not the login credentials are encrypted depends on the encryption capability/configuration of the client and server.

**At the protocol level, completely unencrypted SQL logins are allowed**, though my *guess* is that these are rare because I *suspect* most modern database drivers do not support them.

### Details

Clients communicate with Microsoft SQL Server using the [Tabular Data Stream (TDS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523.aspx) protocol.

Shortly after a client opens a TDS connection to the server, it informs the server of its encryption capability. The server compares this announcement with its own configuration/capability to determine the encryption state for the connection.

In a nutshell, the encryption state is determined as follows:

- If client or server announces that they do not support encryption and the other side does not require encryption, the entire connection—including login—**will be unencrypted**.
- If both client and server announce that they support encryption but do not require it, **just the first TDS packet of the login request will be encrypted**. The remainder of the connection, including any additional login request packets, will be unencrypted. A properly-designed database driver will ensure that the SQL authentication password is placed in first login packet, but this isn't required at the protocol level.
- If either client or server announces that they require encryption, **the entire connection will be encrypted** (except for a small amount of preliminary data)  unless the other side does not support encryption. In that case, the connection will be terminated.

The only way to ensure that login requests are *always* encrypted is to set the 'require encryption' option on either client or server. There’s no option to disallow completely unencrypted connections without requiring full encryption.

Regardless of whether or not the login or connection is encrypted, the SQL authentication password is always obfuscated but the scrambling is easily reversible.

### Further Reading:

- Technical details on connection encryption states - [MS-TDS 2.2.6.5 PRELOGIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd357559.aspx) (under heading *Encryption*)
- Password obfuscation formula - [MS-TDS 2.2.6.4 LOGIN7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304019.aspx) (see last paragraph)
- Slightly more in-depth write-up on the topic - [SQL Passwords: Encrypted Between Client and Server?](https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2017/09/20/3784/sql-passwords-encrypted-between-client-and-server) (disclaimer: this is a post on my blog)

Answer (score 2):

The credentials are sent in clear text.

You can probably find a number of sources for this, but [here's one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998372.aspx#pagpractices0001_authentication):

"Secure the channel between the Web server and database server because credentials are passed in an unencrypted format. For example, use SSL or IPSec."

Comment: Interestingly this is the posting I found that lead to me posting my question.  It also appears to directly contradict this other MSDN post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx

Comment: So either the asp.net best practice guide is wrong or the Encrypting SQL Server 2005 connections MSDN article is wrong....

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to some [security best practices](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/5/e/85eea4fa-b3bb-4426-97d0-7f7151b2011c/SQL2005SecBestPract.doc) for SQL 2005.  That doc states in part:

> In Windows Authentication mode,
>   specific Windows user and group
>   accounts are trusted to log in to SQL
>   Server. Windows credentials are used
>   in the process; that is, either NTLM
>   or Kerberos credentials. Windows
>   accounts use a series of encrypted
>   messages to authenticate to SQL
>   Server; no passwords are passed across
>   the network during the authentication
>   process.  **When SQL logins are used, SQL login passwords are passed across the network for authentication.** This makes SQL logins less secure than Windows logins.

Comment: Think Noel was asking about SQL server auth, not Windows auth

Comment: Quite right, thank you.  Fixed.  In other news, people still use mixed mode? :)

Comment: And it's difficult to use Windows Auth when the client is `NETWORK SERVICE` or some other low-privileged account...

Comment: This doc is also ambiguous.  'When SQL logins are used, SQL login passwords are passed across the network for authentication', but in the clear or via a secure comms protocol?  Also, 'there are security improvements for SQL logins in SQL Server 2005 ... These improvements include ... better encryption when SQL passwords are passed over the network'

Comment: And maddingly 'SQL Server 2005 can use an encrypted channel for two reasons: to encrypt credentials for SQL logins'

It can!  Or it does!!!!!

Comment: 'The other reason for using SSL is to encrypt credentials during the login process for SQL logins when a password is passed across the network.'  However, this doc implies that all this is optional rather than by default.

Answer (score 1):

Reading this thread made me even more confuse then I was!
Anyway, I did some tests with Wireshark, with or without encrypted connection **I was never able to see my password** (and my user name I think). What was very visible without encryption is the actual queries.

Perhaps it is the lack of knowledge with Wireshark to retrieve the login credentials, but since I was able to see everything else I'm pretty sure I was looking at the right spot and the password was ALWAYS hidden.

Comment: TDS (the protocol used for client-to-SQL Server communications) has an encryption state between fully encrypted and fully unencrypted where just the first packet of the login request is encrypted. This state is used when encryption is supported but not required. I wonder if the test you did used this encryption state--which would explain why you couldn't see the username and password.

Comment: Wow, that was long ago... I don't remember what were the configurations, but I doubt I changed anything from the defaults. only thing I can think of was attaching a certificate to the instance.

Comment: I suspect that you were not able to identify your password because it is encoded according to the Tabular Data Stream Protocol (MS-TDS) which is used for client to server communication. The login procedure of TDS and its encoding are detailed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304019.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the fact that passwords are sent in clear text, it is also possible to replace the hash of the password.