# Encrypt SQL Server Connection with IP Address?

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, encryption

I'm doing some tests on how to connect to a DB on SQL Server via IP address.

I would need to connect via an IP address with SQL Server to a database on a VPS.
At this time, I can connect with a user and password using the IP address, but I think that it's too vulnerable.

Is it possible to connect to the DB by using an encrypted connection? Whether with SQL Management Studio and possibly using connectionstring on my application?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server login packets are always encrypted. You can also encrypt all traffic by installing a cert on the server and specifying `force encryption` using SQL Server Configuration Manager. Right-click on "Protocols for MSSQLSERVER" under SQL Server Network Configuration and select properties.

Comment: So without SSL cert it's not possible to see username and password using, for example, wireshark?

Comment: @Federcio2, right, the login traffic is not in clear text. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163658/sql-server-2005-how-secure-is-sql-server-authentication).

Comment: Okay, I just add a certificate on the server. Connection is okay. Thank you, man!